# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method pay(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i'm having a problem with my button when I'm pressing on click this error is showing up

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method pay(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4560)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18636)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is how I declare my `pay(View view)`

```
void pay(View view){
        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(10), "USD", "Test payment with paypal",
                PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, m_configuration);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);
        startActivityForResult(intent, m_paypalRequestCode);
    }
```

And this is the `.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f2f2f2"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_down_payment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.kun.carkila.downPaymentActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_down_payment">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvStatus"
    android:text="Pay Downpayment"
    android:onClick="pay"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/m_response"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pay method should be public.

```
public void pay(View view){
    PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(10), "USD", "Test payment with paypal",
            PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE); 

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, m_configuration);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);
    startActivityForResult(intent, m_paypalRequestCode);
}
```

Comment: Hi @JosephG  you can accept the answer if it helped.